# Get dateTime in DB and convert to string and add in excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, date, datetime, worksheet

I get datetime from database SQL, and convert to string using  `table.Rows.Add(CreatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`
when i open the excel i have diferents formats of dates, and the excel filters had date when it should have only the years as shown in the results in th filters:

[image: Date format inconsistent]

[image: date filters error]

Comment: Yea.. that's the problem with formatting stuff as strings; it tends to be unformatted as something else at the other end/ Just put the date in straight as a date, assuming you're using a library that can handle that (eg EPPLus to make XLSX files) and not being forced output in some low tech format like CSV (in which case you should format string date in ISO, like `2000-01-01 12:34:56`

Comment: I´m using Office.Interop.Excel, so you know some resolution?

Comment: Don't use Office Interop; switching to EPPlus is relatively painless as most of the commands to make the library work are similar/same as interop, and you'll no longer need Excel installed to create excel files

Comment: @CaiusJard, i want a free library. I saw and in the excel some rows was general type and the wrong rows was data type.

Comment: You want free and so you're using an office suite costing hundreds of dollars instead of EPPlus, which is free up to v4 and free v5+ for personal use?

Comment: @CaiusJard, Office for my company is free, and it is not for personal use.

Comment: Office is never free, Microsoft not being a charity and all, you're just choosing not to understand the costs involved. You're also confusing "cost" and "value", failing to appreciate that even free things have a cost, and perhaps also simultaneously a) completely missing the economic sense of paying another developer a small sum to gain access to their efforts that exceed what you can do for the same sum at your hourly rate, and b) expressing the deepest hypocrisy that you expect to be paid for your efforts yet expect all the supporting software you use to be provided to you for free.. Hmm

Comment: Economics and decency rhetoric aside, I have already told you what to do; stop shuttling your data around as a string.. Especially not as a dd/MM/yyyy string, that Excel might choose to interpret as a MM/dd/yyyy string